# Is it safe to delete a shared state using std::atomic_flag as synchronization mechanism

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++20, atomic

I have a shared state that is used by two threads concurrently. At some point, both threads are done using the shared state; it is of no use anymore and must be deleted.

**Question:** is it safe/acceptable/allowed to use `std::atomic_flag` as a synchronization mechanism to determine which thread should delete the shared state?

```cpp
#include <atomic>
#include <thread>

struct State
{
    std::atomic_flag flag;

    auto eliminate() {
        // Setting the flag signals that a thread is done with the state;
        // the second thread should then also delete the state.
        if (flag.test_and_set())
            delete this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto s = new State{};
    auto t1 = std::thread{[=] { s->eliminate(); }};
    auto t2 = std::thread{[=] { s->eliminate(); }};
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

---

I know that either thread must consider the shared state as deleted once a call to `eliminate` returns.

I presume the implementation is safe because the state's members are no longer accessed after the call to `test_and_set`, but I am unsure if the C++ standard allows a construction like this.

My project has a custom linked list of these states and my goal is to prevent the list from growing out of control. If I give one thread clear ownership of the states, it would also be responsible for performing a cleanup routine regularly. I am trying to avoid such mechanisms.

It would be really nice if I could delete the nodes of the list immediately once both threads are done with it.

Comment: IMHO main problem here is that this patter is hard to maintain code (what should happen when you add threads, or remove them). Much more reasonable is to let `main` control lifetime of `*s`. Current code is valid.

Comment: Looks legal, but why not use a `shared_ptr`?

Comment: You could also use a `std::latch` or `std::barrier` to do something once all threads are done, though this may involve blocking threads. You can also use `std::atomic_int` or so if you have more than two threads and use it similarly to your `std::atomic_flag`. Generally, prefer `std::atomic_bool` to `std::atomic_flag`, since `std::atomic_flag` is designed to be lock-free, even if it's vastly more expensive than locking.

Comment: @MarekR I could use `std::atomic_int` to support more than two threads; the last thread decrements to `0` and should delete the state. I agree that clear ownership is preferred but I took it as a challenge to avoid a single owner that would have to regularly perform cleanup.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yep, `std::shared_ptr` would work but why pay for such mechanisms if they're not needed? Consider the question an optimization challenge, not necessarily to be used in production (for now) :)

Comment: @JanSchultke Blocking threads is definitely a no-go. The `eliminate` call may be invoked concurrently or it may be invoked minutes apart.

Comment: You definitely need an atomic int (with release semantics, like `shared_ptr`). Right now `t1` could delete the object while `t2` is still trying to set the flag. Worse, imagine the memory gets reused and the flag's memory reset to zero while `t2` is sleeping

Comment: *"why pay for such mechanisms"* You pay for the confidence in the implementation not being broken. :P

Comment: @Homer512 Can you elaborate why `std::atomic_flag` does not guarantee correct behavior? The value is read and set in one atomic operation so I fail to understand how `t1` could delete the object while `t2` is still setting the flag? Same for memory reuse, how could one thread still be reading while the memory is already being reused?

Comment: Imagine the following events in chronological order: 1. Both threads enter `eliminate()`. 2. `t2` is suspended by the operating system. 3. `t1` sets the flag successfully. 4. `t1` deletes the object. 5. `t1` allocates a new object, by chance reusing the memory from the previously deleted object. 6. `t2` is woken up by the OS. 7. `t2` is still in `eliminate`, has no knowledge that the object was destroyed, tries to set the flag, which now belongs to an entirely different object

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just realize, you invert the logic on who deletes and you only consider two threads. In that case, it works. You can still reduce the strength of the memory order to release semantics. But otherwise it should work, as long as you only have two threads

Comment: Re, "I could use `std::atomic_int`..." Then you would be reinventing `std::shared_ptr`. Re, "why pay for such mechanisms if they are not needed?" If you reinvent it, would that not prove that you _did_ need it? Why pay _extra_ to reinvent, and test your own version instead of just using the library version?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Well, my use case is for 2 threads only, so I don't even need the `std::atomic_int`. Also, I am not necessarily reinventing `std::shared_ptr` because that is more powerful: storing two pointers and storing extra info in the control block I do not need. Consider the question just a challenge in optimization, rather than the sane approach in production code. :)

Comment: The `std::` library probably can do thousands of things that your program doesn't need. But, why pay for such mechanisms if they're not needed?`Why not simply write your own library that does only exactly what your program needs, and no more? If it's wasteful to use a library class that does everything you need _and more,_ then why doesn't that idea apply to the library as a whole?

Comment: @SolomonSlow Exactly! ;)

Comment: `atomic_flag` is not really expected to be any cheaper than `atomic<int>` on any given platform.  The purpose of `atomic_flag` is to be a "least common denominator"; it is required to be lock-free on every platform.  So an extremely primitive platform whose only atomic operations were single bits could still implement `atomic_flag` and then have all other `atomic<T>` be non-lock-free.  But in the real world, `atomic<int>` *is* lock-free on any sensible platform, and has much more useful functionality.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis: "*Exactly!*" I think he was being sarcastic. That is, your idea, taken to its extremes, means never using any library ever for any purpose and therefore writing all your own code.

Comment: Set parallelism aside and assume sequential execution of your threads. Once `t1` finishes, you have `delete`d `s`, and `t2` is exhibiting **use-after-free** on `s`. The problem is not `atomic_flag`, it is raw pointer manipulation.

Comment: @NicolBolas As was I!

Comment: @Red.Wave How is `t2` using `s`? Once the atomic flag is read (and set, atomically), there's no further reads or writes done to `s`, right?

Comment: @MaartenBamelis, are you not calling `eliminate` on `s` in `t2`?. Once it dereferences the pointer to test the flag, a use-after-free has happened.

Comment: @Red.Wave Can you elaborate? My goal was to use the `std::atomic_flag` to ensure only the second thread calls delete.

Comment: @MaartenBamelis I mentioned earlier: the problem is using raw pointers. You should almost never do it. `delete this` is never the smart choice, how can you make sure the object is not referenced after the `delete`? This behavior is difficult to describe, document and maintain. Simply put: **don't**.